# Why am I getting ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, python-import

Here is the directory and file as a tree:

```
.
├── my_dir
│   ├── a.py
│   └── b.py
└── outside.py
```

`a.py` has only one function:

```
def my_func_a():
    return "This is a test from a"
```

In `b.py` I have imported the `a.py` module and used its function inside another function:

```
from a import my_func_a
    
def my_func_b():
    print(my_func_a())
    return "This is a test from b"
```

Now, in `outside.py`, when I am running the code, I am facing the `ModuleNotFoundError`:

```
from my_dir import b

print(b.my_func_b())
```

the Error:

```
from a import my_func_a
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'
```

Comment: can you please try by creating a package for dir `my_dir`? Create empty `__init__.py` file in `my_dir` and try again.

Comment: `from .a import my_func_a`

Comment: I tried it already and created an empty `__init__.py`, but it didn't work!

Comment: Thank you @MattDMo ! This method `from .a import my_func_a` worked fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The importing should be as follows and it is working perfectly!

```
from .a import my_func_a
```